# Decrypting .m3u8 AES 128 .drm file and IV

Tags: encryption, ffmpeg, m3u8

Am trying to get the following video for offline viewing since my connection recently has been flakey.

I've tried ffmpeg with the .m3u8 file but it says "invalid data" as the files are encrypted, I've been trying to read up on how to do it but can't seem to find my exact scenario with this .drm file, everywhere they have the .key file. I've tried downloading each .ts and joining them which is fine but it is still encrypted, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Link to site:
https://www.my5.tv/eamonn-ruth-how-the-other-half-lives/season-2/episode-1

The .m3u8 file starts like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:9
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-FAXS-CM:URI="C5206830001A_1500.drm"

#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://access.adobeprimetime.com/faxsks/axs_prod/key",IV=0x82ecdecae409ca0fedae928a76725804
#EXT-X-MEDIA-TIME:0.0
#EXTINF:9,
```

Comment: I think what I need to do here is to find the key file first, I've looked at the links transmitted over HTTPS but nothing looked like the .key file or something similar, I think once I got the key file its not too hard to decrypt, I think OpenSSL  would be able to do it, or if I'm not mistaken, ffmpeg can do it during the download asking as the .key file is in the same dir ?

Comment: PS: If you figure out how to decrypt their key then you should contact Adobe Prime Time, they'll pay you to show/tell how you outclassed those PhD's they paid to develop this video encryption.

Comment: Haha, guess it's going to be quite tough, there is a token.dat file served which contains some encrypted info but from what I could see it seems to be the auth to allow the hls playback, there's also a .drm file which I think the website serves to adobe, and in response it get's the token.dat file to authorize playback, nobody seems to have talked about this method anywhere yet, wondering if anyone has managed to crack/bypass it yet, also need to find out how/what is decrypting the token.dat file, maybe the .swf file ?